# Convert C# to TypeScript

Tags: c#, typescript

I have to translate C# app into TypeScript. It goes pretty well, but I have a problem with that:

```
Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
jo: JsonObject = new JsonObject(
                 from kv in parameters
                      select new KeyValuePair<string, JsonValue>(kv.Key, new JsonPrimitive(kv.Value)));
```

Does anyone know how to convert this?

Comment: please show what `parameters` is?

Comment: Sorry. Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

Comment: how is `parameters` represented in typescript?

Comment: In JavaScript, an object is basically a hash/dictionary already, so `parameters` is probably already an object (depending on the rest of your TypeScript implementation) so you may not need this code at all.

Comment: @Daniel A. White. ; parameters: ObservableCollection < { key: string; value: string }>();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In typescript the dictionary is pretty much the json object you are looking for:

```
let dict:{[key:string]:string} = {
    'foo':'bar',
    'john':'doe'
}
let jo = dict;
```